# Static Calendar of current month to show in PDF report

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

[image: Calendar to show in PDF]

I need to show a static calendar in pdf having current month dates.
The dates will have different icons as per the condition from database table column values. The requirement is to send a report to end user every month in form of PDF having current month dates.

Please help me to choose which language/technology can assist in creating such a PDF. Will .net , jquery can help to build such web form or web-page which can then be converted to PDF. Is there any similar demo project available online. I have searched a lot but maybe my keywords are not assisting in getting the right direction.

I have attached the image of calendar which needs to be shown in PDF.

*Thanks for all*

Comment: That is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the goal by using iTextsharp and was able to create Calendar having different cell events as per my business logic to have different images.

The link helped me to create a calendar which then I manipulated to have my custom cell events  [Creating a Printable PDF Calendar](http://kuujinbo.info/cs/itext_calendar.aspx)

[calendar in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8oP0.png)

Hope this helps anyone who want to achieve similar requirement.

Answer (score -1):

https://jsreport.net

This seems to satisfy your needs exactly

Didn't try it though.

P.s. 
Would have commented this.